# How to SETFOCUS to a control in a REPORT footer

Tags: ms-access-2010, vba6

I have a report with sums in the footer.  I want to lookup data and assign that data to a textbox in the report footer.

1. in the OPEN event I do a DLOOKUP and get my data.  I try to assign that data to a control but get an error says "You cant assign a value..  All of this is done from the OnOPEN event.

Can someone tell me how and when I can assign the data to the control in the report footer

1.Ive tried googling the answer
2. Tried to assign the data
3. Used Me.controlname and Report!ReportName.Control name

Comment: Your question is not clear. But you can use `reportfooter_print` event to set the control (textbox? label?) value.